# javascript shim for HTML5 Audio issues

Tags: jquery, html, javascript, html5-audio

I am using a javascript shim called audio.js to serve HTML5 audio with a flash fallback.  I have it working now in all modern browsers and Android and iOs, but there's one issue I just can't seem to fix, and that is that in Firefox or Android, when I use the callback fired on track ending, I cannot replay the audio. The file is stuck at the end of playback.

The project is a slideshow whose logic depends on the callbacks fired when each track ends.  Here's how I'm trying to use the callback:

```
audio.trackEnded=function() {

    // operate on the DOM
    }
```

and here's the bit from the audio.js API:

```
trackEnded: function(e) {
      this.skipTo.apply(this, [0]);
      if (!this.settings.loop) this.pause.apply(this);
      this.settings.trackEnded.apply(this);
    }
```

I have not had any luck delving into the API to try to figure out how to reset the audio file.  All I know is that no matter what I put in the trackEnded function, in the browsers that need the flash the file freezes at the end, and when I remove that function, the audio resets just fine.  And trying to operate on the audio element itself, by setting currentTime = 0; breaks the whole thing.

Here's a demo of the audio freezing, which you can see after clicking into the slideshow:

http://www.jontakiff.com/audio-playback/skeleton.html

Any insight into how I might go about solving this would be super appreciated.

Edit: here's a link to the audio.js API: http://kolber.github.com/audiojs/docs/

Comment: are you coding in pure javascript, or are you using a library such as jQuery, dojo, or Mootools?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the comment, just took a look at the pages code. you could try the jQuery Connect plugin.here are some references:

http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/61/posts/11231/what-is-jquery-connect-how-to-use-jquery-connect.aspx

http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jqConnect

and the jquery code would look like this:

```
$.connect(audio,'trackEnded',window,window.trackEnded);
```

note that you need to use trackEnded function as a regular function in the format:

```
function trackEnded(){
    //code here
}
```